# ansible-playbook gather information from a file

Tags: ansible

I want to read a file by ansible and find specific thing and store all of them in a file in my localhost
for example there is `/tmp/test` file in all host and I want to grep specific thing in this file and store all of them in my home.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There might be many ways to accomplish this. The choice of Ansible modules (or even tools) can vary.

One approach is (using only Ansible):

- [Slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) the remote file
- Write new file with filtered content
- Fetch the file to Control machine

**Example:**

```yaml
- hosts: remote_host

  tasks:
  # Slurp the file
  - name: Get contents of file
    slurp:
      src: /tmp/test
    register: testfile

  # Filter the contents to new file
  - name: Save contents to a variable for looping
    set_fact:
      testfile_contents: "{{ testfile.content | b64decode }}"
  - name: Write a filtered file
    lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/filtered_test
      line: "{{ item }}"
      create: yes
    when: "'TEXT_YOU_WANT' in item"
    with_items: "{{ testfile_contents.split('\n') }}"

  # Fetch the file
  - name: Fetch the filtered file
    fetch:
      src: /tmp/filtered_test
      dest: /tmp/
```

This will fetch the file to `/tmp/<ANSIBLE_HOSTNAME>/tmp/filtered_test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ansible fetch module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) to download files from the remote system to your local system. You can then do the processing locally, as shown in this [Ansible cli](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible.html) example:

```
REMOTE=[YOUR_REMOTE_SERVER]; \
ansible -m fetch -a "src=/tmp/test dest=/tmp/ansiblefetch/" $REMOTE && \
grep "[WHAT_YOU_ARE_INTERESTED_IN]" /tmp/ansiblefetch/$REMOTE/tmp/test > /home/user/ansible_files/$REMOTE
```

This snippet runs the ad-hoc version of Ansible, calling the module `fetch` with the source folder (on the remote) and the destination folder (locally) as arguments. Fetch copies the file into a folder `[SRC]/[REMOTE_NAME]/[DEST]`, from which we then `grep` what we are interested in, and output that in the `/home/user/ansible_files/$REMOTE`.